# File selector in the front-end of a specific directory

Tags: front-end, file-upload

I am developing a component which has a front-end form. In this form it must be possible to select and upload a File to a user-specific directory.

I found and tested the module Easy File Uploader and it fits my requirements for uploading files (I am using the option "Upload to Username subfolders". The module will then create a folder for each user). The component only allows me to upload files, but not select them again. I placed the module in my edit-form of the component.

Now i have a directory like this:

- Images

  - User1

    - File1
    - File2
    - File3
    - File4
    - ...
  - User2

    - File1
    - ...

Now i want to be able to select the files again. (So I can store the filepath for the profile image into the Database) I thought about using a simple dropdown, but how can I realize it with the mvc pattern of joomla 3.3?

**EDIT:**

Oh, im a bit blind, so I found the form field "filelist" on the joomla docs: http://docs.joomla.org/Filelist_form_field_type

Is there a way to set the directory in the code dynamically?

Comment: What have you tried to far? Have a look into Joomla's filesystem package, using `JFolder` and `JFile`

Comment: I think i won't have a problem with looping the folder, but how do I apply this data to the form-xml file?

Comment: JForm can take a string as xml as well, so you can create an array structure from the data then convert to xml and pass it to JForm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model, after loading the form, you can use `setFieldAttribute` to set the directory dynamically like so:

```
$form->setFieldAttribute('myfile', 'directory', 'media/media/images');
```